# How to use ref with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to learn Vue3 + Typescript (I so far wrote Vue2 apps with plain JS). I am trying to define a reactive variable in `setup()` :

```
setup() {
    // a single note
    interface Note {
      id: string
      creationDate: string
      text: string
      tags: string[]
      deleted: boolean
    }
    // all the notes in the app
    let allNotes: ref(Note[])  // ← this is not correct
    let allnotes: Note[]  // ← this is correct but not reactive
    
    (...)
  }
```

What is the correct syntax for creating a reactive Array of `Note`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be placed between `<>` :

```
let allNotes= ref<Note[]>([])
```

by default the `ref` infers the type from the initial value like

```
const name=ref('') //name is a type of string
```

Ref typing :

```
interface Ref<T> {
  value: T
}

function ref<T>(value: T): Ref<T>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of making a reactive object for that
It is used for an object

Like @Boussadjra Brahim said add a type to the ref function
like this

```
let reactiveNoteArray = ref<Note[]>([]); //Add this angle bracket when using custom types and interfaces
```